# how can I scale the the numbers in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, numbers, scale, scaling

I have to scale the numbers to be between 0 and 9 how can I do that in flutter application?

my data is from 0.000001 to >500,

and I need it to be from 0 to 9

Comment: Can you provide examples of inputs and their corresponding expected outputs?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is to first normalize the data to the 0-1 range:

```
final normalized = (data - min) / (max - min);
```

And then multiply it by your new max:

```
final converted = normalized * 9;
```

Answer (score 0):

For min-max normalization:

Min= 0.000001
Max= n ( you need to define the upperlimit to replace >500)

New value= (Value * 9) / (max-min)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this & created this method, I am following [scale a number between a range](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/281164/378987)

```dart
/// Scale value between two different range
double scaler(
  double value,
  double start1,
  double stop1,
  double start2,
  double stop2,
) {
  final result =
      ((value - start1) / (stop1 - start1)) * (stop2 - start2) + start2;
  return result;
}
```

And test case

```dart
void main() {
  group('scaler', () {
    test("value 1.5, scale (0,3) to (0,10),  should return 5 ", () {
      final matcher = scaler(1.5, 0, 3, 0, 10);
      expect(5, matcher);
    });
    test("value 1.5, scale (0,3) to (-4.2, 6.7),  should return 1.25 ", () {
      final matcher = scaler(1.5, 0, 3, -4.2, 6.7);
      expect(1.25, matcher);
    });
  });
}
```